# How do I assign multiple values to a variable of the same column in sql server

Tags: sql-server

How do I assign multiple values of the same column in a variable so that I can use the independent values in the programming. Is there any concept of an array in SQL server?

```
SELECT @x= Code FROM Security WHERE Department=@dpt;
```

This works correctly when code has single value, but when code has multiple values it provides errors.

Comment: you must provide the sample data..

Comment: u can use cursor in this case

Comment: There is no concept of an array in SQL Server.

Comment: I mean you can fake it using a 1-N relationship to a join table query. There's no concept of an array in any SQL system I've used, just the 1-N/N-1/N-N table relationships.

Answer (score 0):

There are no arrays in SQL Server.

There are [table variables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175010.aspx) though which are similar in usage to temporary tables.

As described on MSDN:

> `table` is a special data type that can be used to store a result set for processing at a later time. table is primarily used for temporary storage of a set of rows returned as the result set of a table-valued function. Functions and variables can be declared to be of type table. table variables can be used in functions, stored procedures, and batches.

You can use it this way:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE (Code int)

INSERT INTO @x
SELECT Code FROM Security WHERE Department=@dpt
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways I can think, depending on what you are planning to do...

1. declare @mytable table (Code Int)
   Insert into @mytable
   select Code from security where Department =@dpt.
2. declare @x nvarchar(max)
   set @x = "";
   select @x = cast(Code as Nvarchar(max))  + "," + @x from Security WHERE Department=@dpt;

now you have the data as comma seperated string, you can then further split it into a table like #1 above or send it out as string, which the program can consume.